# Writing on Images

Tags: documentclass-writing, picture-mode

I hope you are having a nice day.
There are a lot of Instagram pages that use LaTeX to write on images. Is it possible to write on images? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: You could take a look at for example the  [`overpic` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/overpic).

Comment: Okay I will see to that. Thanks

Comment: Or check a solution with TIKZ: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/359071#359071